# unable to use parseFloat after JSON Stringify

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I have a line of code which says --

```
var latitude = JSON.stringify(place.lat);
```

when I do alert(latitude) -- It gives me output "33.232342" .But I want the number so when I do

```
var latitude = parseFloat(JSON.stringify(place.lat));
```

I get NaN. Could someone tell me what the problem might be?

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `place.lat`? It may actually be the source of your problem.

Comment: This is the JSON is used {"lat":"33.424042","lng":"-111.938744"} ..

Comment: Why would you stringify a number to parse it as is, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `place.lat` is already a `string`. So doing `JSON.stringify()` makes `""33.232342""`.
Just:

```
parseFloat(place.lat);
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` turns primitives into strings, so:

```
JSON.stringify(5.1)
```

returns the 5-character string

```
"5.1"
```

Passing such a value into `parseFloat` results in `NaN`. **Simply don't `JSON.stringify` the value**, and your code should work fine.

It's worth noting that the [JSON spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) only allows objects and arrays as top-level elements in a JSON representation, so it's not spec-compliant to "JSON-ify" a raw number (but your browser will do it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that place.lat is a string, so when you stringify it, you get a string with quotes.

That's the same result than with

```
parseFloat(JSON.stringify("3.5"))
```

that is

```
NaN
```

A solution would be to directly parse place.lat : `parseFloat(place.lat)`

If you want to parse a number which is in a string with quotes, you may also do

```
parseFloat(str.slice(1,-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem roots here:

`JSON.stringify(place.lat)` returns `"' 20.0120132312'"`, which has a leading `'` in it. Just use:

```
parseFloat(place.lat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you `JSON.stringify`ing it if it's already an object?

Just do `parseFloat(place.lat)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke:

```
parseFloat(JSON.parse(latitude))
```